# Get Parent index array multydimension

Tags: php, arrays

I'm dealing with php array and I have proplem with get the index of parent array. Here I want to find parent index of title so I try find it by loop but I failed find index if the title is array. How I can get the parent index if the title is array

```
<?php
$Arr = [
    [
        "title" => ["news", "nasional", "internasional", "regional", "metropolitan", "sains", "pendidikan"],
        "url" => "AAA",
    ],
    [
        "title" => ["seleb", "news"],
        "url" => "BBB"
    ],
    [
        "title" => "travel",
        "url" => "CCC"
    ]
];


foreach($Arr as $value) {
$key = array_search("seleb", array_column($Arr , 'title'));
    echo $key; // should return index parent is [1]
}

?>
```

Comment: so you want to return parent index  0 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find the parent index

```
$Arr = [
        [
          "title" => ["news", "nasional", "internasional", "regional", "metropolitan", "sains", "pendidikan"],
          "url" => "AAA",
       ],
       [
         "title" => ["seleb", "news"],
         "url" => "BBB"
       ],
       [
         "title" => "travel",
         "url" => "CCC"
       ]
      ];

   foreach($Arr as $key => $value) {
     if(is_array($value['title'])){
        if(in_array("seleb", $value['title']))
           echo $key;
     }
   }
```

Comment: I see, so we can treat key as parent index. thank you for sharing your thought

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the whole array instead of it pass the current value of the loop

```
foreach ($Arr as $key => $value) {
    $keyChild='';
    $keyChild = array_search("seleb", $value);
    if ($keyChild != null && empty($keyChild)) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it with a little less nesting and a bit more re-usability

```
<?php
$arr = [
    [
        "title" => ["news", "nasional", "internasional", "regional", "metropolitan", "sains", "pendidikan"],
        "url" => "AAA",
    ],
    [
        "title" => ["seleb", "news"],
        "url" => "BBB"
    ],
    [
        "title" => "travel",
        "url" => "CCC"
    ]
];

function findIndex($search, $array) {
    $found  = array_filter($array, function ($value) use ($search) {
        if (!is_array($value)) $value = [$value];
        return array_search($search, $value) !== false;
    });

    return key($found);
}

$titles = array_column($arr, 'title');
echo findIndex('seleb', $titles); // 1
```

`findIndex` will return the parent index or null deepening on whether the result is found or not.

Also this part:

```
$titles = array_column($arr, 'title');
```

Could be placed inside the function, with the `'title'` being passed as another parameter.